# Store List of objects in Session/HttpSession object in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Hi all i want to store list of objects in session object. 
To store 1 obj i've got this code:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("temp")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController {
    @ModelAttribute("temp")
    public Temp setObj() {
        return new Temp();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("temp", new Temp());
        return "testInput";
    }

    @RequestMapping()
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("temp") Temp temp, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("temp", temp);
        return "test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get") // or "/getList" to ensure it works
    public String kek(@ModelAttribute("temp") Temp temp, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("temp", temp);
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Where

```
class Temp implements Serializible {
    //constructor fields, methods
}
```

**P.S. storing 1 object works fine.**

But how can i store `List<Temp>` in Session object and add extra `Temp` obj with controller? Or maybe i should use smth like:

```
class TempList {
    private List<Temp> list
    //constructor, get/set addToList methods
}
```

If yes, how can i init this class and use `tempListObj.addToList(Temp temp)` method?

Comment: What does it mean "init this class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information if your store object into session with @SessionAttributes annotation so this object will be available only in scope of this controller. If you want to store List to session, you can just define @SessionAttributes({"temp"}) on class level, and set this into session in any controller method like this:

```
model.addAttribute("temp", new ArrayList<Temp>());
```

Then you can get access to this by this way:

```
public String someMethod(@ModelAttribute("temp") List<Temp> temp) {...}
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("tempObj", new Temp());
        model.addAttribute("list", new ArrayList<Temp>());
        return "testInput";
    }

    @RequestMapping()
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("temp") List<Temp> list, @ModelAttribute("tempObj") Temp temp, Model model) {

        list.add(temp);
        model.addAttribute("list", list);
        return "test";
    }`

Comment: I added code like this, but i've got `Expected session attribute 'temp'` but i added `model.addAttribute("temp", new ArrayList<Temp>())`

Comment: I'm glad that helped you.